# Same file can't upload in Safari & IE9 once cancelled upload

Tags: jquery, node.js, safari, internet-explorer-9

Now here is where i am getting stuck up,

1. User clicks link.
2. User selects a file
3. User clicks okay
4. I upload the file. 
   So far so good,
5. User clicks link.
6. User selects a file
7. User clicks OK
8. I upload the file.
9. User once again clicks link
10. User selects SAME file again.
11. Can't upload the file (obviously since the path is the same)

Comment: Posting some code, and showing what you attempted would greatly increase your chances of getting help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Actually i can't get the file input data while edit the file input again..